# How do I grout a marble and metal linear mosaic tile backsplash

Tags: tile

I am installing a marble and aluminum back splash in my kitchen.  I have read that the marble should be sealed prior to and after grouting. I found a sealer suitable for marble, but it says to avoid contact with metal and other surfaces.  Does the marble have to be sealed prior to grouting?  Is there a sealer suitable for the aluminum?

Comment: You should try to find some more detail about the mosaic tiles.  My guess is that the marble is already pre-sealed or something has been done so that it does not need to be sealed.

Comment: I have contacted the tile manufacturer/distributor but have not yet received any response from them  I also spoke with the manufacturer of the sealer I was going to use.  They said that sealing prior to grouting was not necessary ,but would help in removing the haze after grouting.  They also said it would not harm the aluminum, (this agrees with the results of the test I did on some scrap tiles)